# How can I run my function for some number of minutes?

Tags: python, function

I am writing a simple program to keep clicking my screen (for roblox clicking simulator). But is there a way to run my function autoclicker for 20 minutes using a while loop? The while true makes the function run infinitely and I only want it to run for 20 minutes.

```
    import time
    import mouse


    def autoclicker(n):
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            for i in range(1, 13):
                mouse.click('left')
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can save your start time and check that in an interval, if the difference is higher than your 20 minutes, do your stuff

Comment: So there is a "game" in which the goal is... to click as much as possible... That seems already pretty uninteresting, but what the point of automating such a game??

Comment: @mozway. To be fair, automation is exactly how we are supposed to deal with monotonously repetitive tasks. I agree that this is a horrible and contrived usecase, but still...

Comment: @MadPhysicist of course, yes, here I am just wondering what could be interesting in this "game". I guess an even more horrible goal, "earning" and selling items as many "free" games have this parallel economy built in.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `while True` to test for the limit:

```
end = time.time() + 20 * 60
while time.time() < end:
    for i in range(1, 13):
        mouse.click('left')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try this

```py
import time
import mouse

def autoclicker(n):

    time_1 = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")  #getting initial time

    minPass = 0
    while minPass < 20:  #check if required time ellapesed 

        time.sleep(5)
        for i in range(1, 13):
            mouse.click('left')
        time.sleep(1)

        time_2 = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S") #getting current time
        minPass = int(str(time_2 - time_1).split(':')[1])  #extracting minute part from time difference
```

Comment: Using datetime here is massively over-engineered imo. You could just use a timestamp integer and subtract the difference that way.